# How can I recover my data after choosing “Erase disk and install Ubuntu”?

Tags: data-recovery, partitioning, testdisk

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and chose the option "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" from liveUSB without any backup. When I realized that this would format my whole HDD, I immediately unplugged the usb and turn off my laptop. However, it seems that my whole HDD had been formatted: I have 4 partitions before but there's only 1 partition formatted in ext4 now with the size equal the HDD's size.

Is there anyway I can get my data back? I believe that my data is still there on the disk. I've searched for a while and tried using Testdisk and parted but no luck: Testdisk cannot find any partition even after trying "Deeper Search"

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu might have completely installed by now, has it? Else, what do you see when you boot up?

Comment: The only thing I ever saw working: http://www.partition-tool.com/partition-recovery-wizard/recover-repartitioned-drives.htm

Comment: @Jobin: Yes, Ubuntu has not been completely installed cause I stopped the installation process. When I boot up now, the screen just shows "No operating system found"

Comment: maybe read this and the answer given..
http://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/post6135.html#p6135

Comment: also some links to possibly useful software..
http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Data_Recovery

Comment: If you need to recover data you believe may be lost, it's imperative you immediately shut down the newly installed system and not use it. You can run from a live CD *provided that swap is disabled*. See [the guidelines here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery). Once you've booted into an Ubuntu live CD system, please run `sudo fdisk -l` in a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and **edit your question** to provide the full output (format it with the `<$>` tool so it appears correctly). That should show what partitions there are, and facilitate knowing if data recovery is needed.

Comment: This question seems to have been abandoned. There has not been further information or activity added to it for several months, and you have not logged in since shortly after it was first posted.  I am flagging this to be closed. If you think this issue is still affecting you, you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Comment: @MartinThornton: we have 5 close reasons:  1. duplicate 2.
off-topic 3. unclear what you're asking 4. too broad (=too many possible answers) 5. primarily opinion-based.  The above is none of those, so I'm **voting to keep it open** (sorry about that, but thank you for leaving a comment)  **;-)**